# How can I get a numbered list with a hanging indent?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

**I want to have numbered text lines like:**

> 1. This is line 1
> 2. This is line 2....................................................which when gets to 2nd line doesn't come under the number.
> 3. Line 3

**A normal TextView might get me this:**

> 2.This is line 2...........................................................which when gets to 2nd line comes under the number.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: @Manishika I tried simple TextView like the 2nd case. Since that didn't work my next choice would be, using 2 TextView, 1 for the number and the other for the text. Which doesn't look like a perfect solution. :(

Comment: Your string is static or dynamic ?

Comment: @Prince They are dynamic.

Comment: What do you input into the textview? I would have thought "1.\tThis is line 1\n2.\tThis is line 2\n3.\tThis is line 3" would work.

Comment: @cYrixmorten The problem is about text coming below the numbers(Like in the 2nd example in my question).

Comment: post ur code ..bcoz it not clear wat u r trying